# Images showing in simulator but not on the iPhone device

Tags: iphone, uiimage, ios-simulator, device

So when I run the application from the device the pictures show up and everything works great. However, when I move to the device I run in about 10 out of 38 pictures that don't show up.  I am pulling the names for the images from an sqlite database and I already checked and the names are correct, case and everything.  I checked the bundle and the images are correctly in there.

Does memory play into effect in this?  I am not really sure what else could cause this to happen??

Thanks!

Solution:
The files somehow were not saved properly and were unable to be opened by say photoshop or paint even.  So with the files not being able to be open they weren't showing up... Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simulator accepts a wider range of image formats. Sometimes you had a specific file type that the device cannot display. Double check the 10 files looking for some difference from the others ones.

Answer (score 45):

First thing to check is the case of the strings you're using to refer to the resources. The iPhone is case sensitive, but the simulator is not.

Oops, just seen that you checked the case. Better log all your UIImage creation calls then!

Comment: This helped me. The simulator itself seems to be case-insensitive for the imageNamed part of UIImage, but the device is strict about it.

Comment: This helped me also.

Comment: I was just about to ask a question about this but found the answer right here... Is there any chance that Apple will change the behaviour of their IOS-Simulator ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, memory absolutely plays into this. Check your UIImage creation calls and make sure they dont return empty. Also, check to see if youre getting memory warnings in the console window.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if in-memory size was the culprit, your application would crash with a low memory error on the device.  However, it seems like the images just don't display.

One other thing that can be going wrong is the size of the images.  UIViews on the iPhone can only have dimensions smaller than the maximum texture size supported by the GPU.  Apple states that this is 1024 x 1024, but I've found it to be more like 2048 x 2048 on even the original model iPhone.  You may be creating a view for some of these images that exceeds this size in one dimension, but your Mac has a larger maximum texture size on its GPU and so it displays fine in the Simulator.

Comment: just a comment about the image size, the double size is due to the new iPhone 4. You are now able to make images double the size for resolution.  I believe its as simple as having to images one with the original size of the image and original name, the second with the image name + "@x2" or "@2" that is twice the size/resolution.

Comment: @Matt - No, the difference in maximum texture size is not due to the iPhone 4, it is an inherent limitation of the GPU used.  I have been able to use 2048 x 2048 layers and textures since iPhone OS 2.0 on the original iPhone, so it's unrelated to the new Retina display capabilities.  This is just a case of Apple's documentation differing from actual hardware, which may be just them being conservative in case GPU specs change in the future.

Comment: The max resolution is stated as 2048 for the PowerVR SGX Regarding the images: we found that our app doesnt crash if the images are too big or if there isnt enough memory. The ios dumps other images that arent being displayed and then when you come back to them they simply arnt there. The console however displays a memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the iPhone caches the launch screens. So in my case, I had to reboot my iPhone before being able to see the image.