# One screen is missing from app in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-5

recently I uploaded an app to app store after checking all issues in simulator, all were working well. When I downloaded the app in iphone 5 one of the screen is missing and instead of that a black screen is getting appeared. I checked the simulator to ensure if its there or not but the simulator for iphone 4 retina is doing good, what could be the issue.

P.S:- I have all screen in three sizes, 320X480, 640X960, 1136X640 and named them as the rules like x.png, x@2x.png and x-568h@2x.png. Only the background screen is missing, all other controls are getting appeared.

Comment: What are the exact names of the missing assets as opposed to the ones that are there? And to be clear - you're talking about background images, right? Usually a missing screen would mean nothing appearing at all, to me at least.

Comment: @CarlVeazey, yeah thts why I mentioned only background, because other controls like buttons are appeared but not the background image, will that be because I left "h" from x-568h@2x.png, I actually named it x-568@2x.png and at the time of infating it on screen I was calling it by x-568h@2x.png. However in simulator its appearing.

Comment: images are case sensitive which works well on simulator but not on the phone. for E.g. if your image name is img.JPG and you put it in simulator with img.jpg will work fine but on iOS device it will not work. you'll need the name img.JPG exact as image name for devices. (find difference in extansion capitalizaion in image name). Hope this help.

Comment: so @wasim as you advised and as I said I named it "x-568@2x.png" and calling it by "x-568h@2x.png" may be thats the issue, shall i try and upload the app with version 1.1 with minor bug fix????

Comment: first try testing the app on device.if it works fine on device than you can upload the app.@Saty

Comment: @wasim...I am a new developer...I dont own a iphone 5...in such case, what should I do? please help me out.

Comment: you can create an ipa fie and then test on the device (iphone 5)that you have mention in the question.if that's not possible and if you're sure that the problem was in image name than you can sure upload it.

Comment: can wrong image name cause this type of issue in spite of the fact it is working well in simulator? I can make .ipa file but where would i get a iphone 5, its out of my budget?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485790/images-showing-in-simulator-but-not-on-the-iphone-device and google some you will find more issues and their solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25651/discussion-between-wasim-and-saty)